# If $C(G)$ is the commutator of $G$, then $C(G\times H)=C(G)\times C(H)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is a yes or no question.

I have proved this myself and i'm not sure whether i'm wrong.

> Let $C(G)$ denote the commutator subgroup of a given group $G$.
>
> Let $G,H$ be groups.
>
> Then $C(G\times H) = C(G)\times C(H)$.

Is this true?

Comment: yes ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @mesel Thank you :) !!

Comment: you are welcome :)

Comment: Please try and use more standard notation. The normal meaning of $C(G)$ is the centralizer of $G$, whereas the commutator subgroup is demnoted by $G'$ or by $[G,G]$.

Comment: ... or $D(G)$ (derived subgroup).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for $a,b \in G;\ x,y \in H$, we have:

$([a,b],[x,y]) = (aba^{-1}b^{-1},xyx^{-1}y^{-1}) = (a,x)(b,y)(a,x)^{-1}(b,y)^{-1} = [(a,x),(b,y)]$